# Check 5 last rows - How many empty rows in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to check whether the 5 last rows in my Google Spreadsheet are empty.

I have this code:

```
function addRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow();

  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);

  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 10);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 10, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

And when 5 last rows are not empty, run this code with an "on edit" function.

Answer (score 1):

The `sh.getMaxRows()` method can be used to get the total number of rows in the sheet, whether they have content or not.  Then subtract the last row from the max rows to get how many rows at the end are empty.  To have this run when the sheet is edited, you must "install" a trigger.  From the Edit menu, click "Current project's triggers" and add a new trigger.

```
function addRow() {
  var howManyEmptyRows,sh,ss,lCol,lRow,range,totalRowsInSheet;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  lRow = sh.getLastRow();

  totalRowsInSheet = sh.getMaxRows();
  Logger.log('totalRowsInSheet: ' + totalRowsInSheet)

  howManyEmptyRows = totalRowsInSheet - lRow;
  Logger.log('howManyEmptyRows: ' + howManyEmptyRows)

  lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);

  if (howManyEmptyRows < 6) {//There are 5 or less empty rows at the end of the sheet
    sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 10);
    range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 10, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
  }

}
```